# BatchScript to loop through log files and write specific tokens to a new file

Tags: batch-file

I want to extract information from a bunch of log files, more specifically from only the 2nd and 3rd items on each line of the log files, to be written to a new file.

Problem is also that many of these entries are replicated in every log file, so I do not want to write duplicate tokens/entries to the new file I am writing to.

Basically it is a bunch of log files containing login information - The IP and Username is on the 2nd and 3rd positions of each line in the log files. So I only want to extract that information once, since users log in many times, and write each unique IP and username to a new single log file.

I have the following:

```
for /f "tokens=2,3" in 'FTP_logs\*.log' >> ftp_ips.txt
```

This does not work however.

Thanks

Comment: You can use a tool like `uniq` on the resulting file but a sample of the text would help to give you an exact solution.

Answer (score 1):

```
@echo off
setlocal

rem Process all .log files
(for %%f in (Ftp_logs\*.log) do (
   rem For each file, process tokens 2,3
   for /F "usebackq tokens=2,3" %%a in ("%%f") do (
      rem If this combination had not appeared before...
      if not defined comb[%%a-%%b] (
         rem Echo it and create the combination
         echo %%a %%b
         set "comb[%%a-%%b]=1"
      )
   )
)) > ftp_ips.txt
```

**EDIT**: *Reply to the comments*

My program had a small bug, that is fixed now; however...

When there are any "File/Path not found errors" in a solution, it is up to you to fix they. You know what the real path/file names exist in your computer, so a simple adjustment in the code may made it to run.

You always should post an example of the real data, so we can copy it and use it in our solutions. If you don't post any data, we base our solutions on the information you provided.

Accordingly to your description, each log file have lines similar to these ones:

```
token1 IPone USERone
token1 IPone USERtwo
token1 IPtwo USERone
token1 IPthree USERtwo
```

I prepared three example files and run my solution (with the bug fixed) with they. Below is the output of the test session:

```
C:\Users\Antonio\Documents\Test> dir
 El volumen de la unidad C no tiene etiqueta.
 El número de serie del volumen es: 0895-160E

 Directorio de C:\Users\Antonio\Documents\Test

26/08/2015  10:49 a. m.    <DIR>          .
26/08/2015  10:49 a. m.    <DIR>          ..
26/08/2015  10:33 a. m.    <DIR>          Ftp_logs
26/08/2015  10:44 a. m.               414 test.bat
               1 archivos            414 bytes
               3 dirs  421,700,231,168 bytes libres

C:\Users\Antonio\Documents\Test> dir Ftp_logs
 El volumen de la unidad C no tiene etiqueta.
 El número de serie del volumen es: 0895-160E

 Directorio de C:\Users\Antonio\Documents\Test\Ftp_logs

26/08/2015  10:33 a. m.    <DIR>          .
26/08/2015  10:33 a. m.    <DIR>          ..
26/08/2015  10:32 a. m.               204 One.log
26/08/2015  10:34 a. m.               216 Three.log
26/08/2015  10:33 a. m.               210 Two.log
               3 archivos            630 bytes
               2 dirs  421,700,231,168 bytes libres

C:\Users\Antonio\Documents\Test> type Ftp_logs\One.log
token1 IPone USERone
token1 IPone USERtwo
token1 IPone USERthree
token1 IPtwo USERone
token1 IPtwo USERtwo
token1 IPtwo USERthree
token1 IPone USERone
token1 IPone USERtwo
token1 IPone USERthree

C:\Users\Antonio\Documents\Test> type Ftp_logs\Two.log
token1 IPtwo USERone
token1 IPtwo USERtwo
token1 IPtwo USERthree
token1 IPthree USERone
token1 IPthree USERtwo
token1 IPthree USERthree
token1 IPtwo USERone
token1 IPtwo USERtwo
token1 IPtwo USERthree

C:\Users\Antonio\Documents\Test> type Ftp_logs\Three.log
token1 IPone USERone
token1 IPone USERtwo
token1 IPone USERthree
token1 IPthree USERone
token1 IPthree USERtwo
token1 IPthree USERthree
token1 IPthree USERone
token1 IPthree USERtwo
token1 IPthree USERthree

C:\Users\Antonio\Documents\Test> test

C:\Users\Antonio\Documents\Test> type ftp_ips.txt
IPone USERone
IPone USERtwo
IPone USERthree
IPtwo USERone
IPtwo USERtwo
IPtwo USERthree
IPthree USERone
IPthree USERtwo
IPthree USERthree
```

**VERY IMPORTANT**: Before you post *any* further comment here, you must make a copy of the data I used in my test and run the program with the *same data*. After that, if the program still don't run with your real data, you must compare both data in order to find the differences and post this information in your next comment (if any).

Finally, you never should downvote any answer just because "it don't works", specially if you don't provided any feedback that aids to fix the problem. Remember that you are requesting our help and we provided it for free...

Comment: Hi Aacini. Thank you, but it does not seem to work any better, it still creates duplicates, moreover, it keeps on repeating the following errors:

Comment: The system cannot find the path specified.
The system cannot find the path specified.
The system cannot find the path specified.
The system cannot find the path specified.
'-]' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
'-]' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
The system cannot find the path specified.
The system cannot find the path specified.

Comment: Hi Aacini. Really sorry for downvoting, I never do that for help I am asking, that is just rude. It was a mistake - I wanted to upvote but pressed the wrong button, and when I tried to correct it, it did not want to allow me. I will test this with my data and get back to you. Also, I checked the paths and they were fine, so I am not sure why I got those errors..Thanks A LOT for your help so far.

Answer (score -1):

`for /f` won't recognize "FTP_logs\" as a folder, instead, `for` with no forms do.
To achive that, wrap entire `for /f` inside a `for` loop.

```
for %%a in (Ftp_logs\*.log) do (
    for /f "tokens=2,3" %%b in (%%a) do (echo %%b %%c >> ftp_ips.txt)
)
```

And also, redirection in batch is done by using `echo SOMETHING >> file.txt`.

Comment: Hi Dark Fang. Thanks, seem to be working, but as foxidrive is saying, it seems to be looping through endlessly and it duplicates all duplicate entries - I only want one combination of username/ip address, not everytime they appear in the logs, and some of them have many many entries.